# Git / GitHub - Commit da mesma pessoa, usuários diferentes. GitHub não contabilizando todas minhas atividades (contribuições)

Tags: git, github, commit

### Dúvida

Gostaria depreencher essa minha tabela de contribuições / atividade pra mostrar que não fiquei parado esse tempo todo que mostra.

[image: Tabela de contribuição / atividade no GitHub]

E pelo que percebi, alguns dos meus commits estão com outro usuário, sem login.
Tem alguma forma de eu alterar esse outro usuário, ou vincular ele ao outro, para que ambos os commits contabilizem na minha tabela de contribuição?
[image: Lista de commits no GitHub]

---

### Mais informações:

- O projeto foi iniciado no início de 2021 no Visual Studio Code e o repositório GIT hospedado no Azure DevOps. Os commits eram feitos por comandos no terminal
- Agora migrei para o Visual Studio Community por volta de Setembro / Outubro e criei um segundo Remote hoje (novembro) para poder ter um repositório GIT, somente para contabilizar essas atividades. Repositório Azure continua sendo o principal. Commits agora são feitos direto pela interface do VS Community.
  hospedado no GitHub, para preencher a tabela.
- No Azure DevOps e Visual Studio Community estou usando e-mail estudantil, da instituição.
- No GitHub estou usando e-mail pessoal. Quando usava o Visual Studio Code não me lembro quais eram as credenciais para o push.
- De vez em quando alterno entre 2 computadores pessoais. Mas no VS Community ja constatei que as credenciais estão idênticas, como na imagem ao final.
- Apesar disso, as vezes parece que os commits são em usuários aleatorios, como vou mostrar nas imagens a seguir.

[image: GIT integrado ao Visual Studio Community]

Aqui é uma imagem no repositório remoto do AzureDevOps, mostrando também os usuários diferentes.
[image: Imagem no Azure DevOps]

---

Abaixo tem a comparação dos mesmos commits no GitHub e Azure DevOps, repectivamente.

### GitHub:

[image: Lista de commits no GitHub]

### Azure DevOps:

[image: Commits no Azure DevOps]

Como da pra ver, alguns commits estão feitos usando um e-mail, outros usando outro e-mail.
Cada e-mail é reconhecido em uma plataforma, e não reconhecido na outra.

- GitHub > E-mail pessoal.
- Azure DevOps > Email da Instituição

Estranho que todos os 3 commits das imagens foram feitos pelo Visual Studio Community, que esta logado com o e-mail da Instituição, mas as vezes faz commit com e-mail pessoal.

[image: Tela Visual Studio Community]
[image: Contas Visual Studio Community]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, tu estás usando dois usuários diferentes. Verifique isso com:

```
git config -l
```

Procure por `user.name` e `user.email`. Esses são os dados que estão sendo usados pelo git. Se por acaso aparecer (windows ou mac) `credential.helper=manager`, tu poderás acessar essas configurações direto no teu computador, nas configurações de credenciais (para mim, aparece `Credential Manager`, pois meu Windows tá em inglês). Mas tu também podes alterar com os seguintes comandos pela linha de comando:

```
git config [--global] --replace-all user.name "Full Name"
git config [--global] --replace-all user.email "email@address.com"
```

Com relação a juntar os usuários, tu podes tentar [esse passo a passo](https://docs.github.com/pt/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#about-commit-email-addresses) ([mais detalhes sobre as contribuições](https://docs.github.com/pt/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#common-reasons-that-contributions-are-not-counted)) para adicionar o e-mail na tua conta de usuário:

1. Clique na foto do teu perfil de usuário, na página do git, e depois em settings para entrar nas configurações.
2. Vá para Emails.
3. Em "Add email address", coloque o e-mail desejado.
4. Tu receberás um e-mail de validação para verificar se é válido.
5. Depois disso, selecione o e-mail primário que tu desejas usar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Leonardo. 
Com os comandos `git config user.name` e `git config user.email` eu verifiquei que esta meu e-mail pessoal mesmo.    
A propósito, acho que faltou informar que quando estava no VS Code eu fazia os comandos GIT pelo terminal, e no VS Community estou usando a interface própria da IDE. Mas que mesmo assim cria esta confusão.

Comment: *Somente um nome e um e-mail, em `user.name` e `user.email`

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Minha resposta resolveu o problema? Ou ficou faltando algo? Se resolveu, tu podes aceitá-la. Se não resolveu, me diga o que não funcionou ou não está claro, para eu editar a resposta...

Comment: Fiz os comandos que você disse (tirando os `--global` de dentro dos colchetes, pra funcionarem), mas ainda não tenho como afirmar se agora os commits serão apenas de um usuário sem fazer varios. 

Mas o principal problema mesmo era fazer o GitHub reconhecer ambos os usuários como eu, pra contabilizar ambos os commits nas minhas atividades.

Comment: Coloquei alguns passos que encontrei para vincular os usuários. Espero que isso te ajude, Henrique!

Comment: Ajudou Leonardo, muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo que queria!

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode configurar novamente suas configurações, passando as credenciais corretas:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Fulano de Tal"
$ git config --global user.email fulanodetal@exemplo.br
```

se remover a flag --global você as configura credenciais especificamente para o repositório que estiver fazendo a configuração:

```
$ git config user.name "Fulano de Tal"
$ git config user.email fulanodetal@exemplo.br
```

Ou seja, sem o global você pode utilizar uma identidade diferente para cada projeto/repositório.

ou na raiz do repositório, você pode editar o arquivo de configuração do git:

```
$ sudo vim .git/config
```

e alterar suas credenciais: user/email

Agora basta reconfigurar seuas credencias para assinatura para as credenciais corretas.